# How to handle switch button in navigation drawer- Android Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin

I  have a navigation Drawer menu in my app and in one item i added a switch button. However, i couldn't reach the switch button to handle it. Here is my Switch layout;

(This switch button will be open or close notifications. In the image below, "Bildirimler" means notifications in Turkish.)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.appcompat.widget.SwitchCompat
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/mySwitchID"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:padding="64dp"
    android:checked="true"
    />
```

My Menu xml,

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto">
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:id="@+id/myFavourites"
        android:title="Favorilerim"
        />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:id="@+id/rateUs"
        android:title="Bizi Değerlendirin"
        />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:id="@+id/notifications"
        android:title="Bildirimler"
        app:actionLayout="@layout/menu_switch"
        app:showAsAction="always"
        />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:id="@+id/item4"
        android:title="item4"
        />
    <item
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"
        android:id="@+id/item5"
        android:title="item5"
        />

    <item android:title="Yana ok" >
        <!-- Normalde bu yana ok yapar ama bizde alt başlık gibi olcak -->

        <menu>

            <item
                android:id="@+id/item6"
                android:title="Yan1"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"


                />
            <item
                android:id="@+id/item7"
                android:title="Yan2"
                android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher_foreground"

                />

        </menu>

    </item>

</menu>
```

And my Main Activity,

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var binding: ActivityMainBinding
    lateinit var toggle : ActionBarDrawerToggle

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        binding = ActivityMainBinding.inflate(layoutInflater)
        setContentView(binding.root)

        val drawerLayout : DrawerLayout = findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout)
        val navView : NavigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view)

        toggle = ActionBarDrawerToggle(this,drawerLayout,R.string.open,R.string.close)
        drawerLayout.addDrawerListener(toggle)
        toggle.syncState()

        supportActionBar?.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true)

        navView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener {
            when(it.itemId){
                
                R.id.notifications -> {


                }

            }
            true
        }



    }

    override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

        if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
            return true
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)


    }

}
```

[image]

I saw some solutions for Java but not Kotlin.

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem by changin my fun like below,

override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {

```
    val switch_id : SwitchCompat? = findViewById(R.id.mySwitchID)

    switch_id?.let {
        it.setChecked(true);
        it.setOnCheckedChangeListener { compoundButton, b ->

            if (b){
                Toast.makeText(this, "True", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                println("true")
            }
            else {
                Toast.makeText(this, "False", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                println("false")
            }
        }
    }

    if(toggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)){
        return true
    }
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)




}
```